# End If does not immediately continue if the statement is true

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I am seeing some odd behaviour in the VB.Net End If statement when it has a breakpoint set. When the If statement is false the program arrives at the End If breakpoint and will continue after clicking continue.  When the If statement is true the program arrives at the breakpoint but it does not continue after pressing continue. You have to press continue a second time. Is this normal? I'm asking the question because I am having trouble debuggging a subroutine and while this is probably my fault the End If behaviour is the only thing I can see at this time that I can't explain. The code below with breakpoints set on the End If's is all that is needed to test this and it can be placed anywhere. I used two buttons.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If 1 = 0 Then
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If 1 = 1 Then
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I can confirm the behaviour but I've never actually noticed it before. I guess I probably never put breakpoints on `End If` statements. If you put the breakpoint on an earlier line and step to the `End If` then you don't see that behaviour. I doubt that it's related to your other issue as it's apparently never affected me.

Comment: It might be interesting to look at the generated IL and/or the disassembly to see if there's an artifact that would explain the behavior.  One thought that occurs to me is that the way the code is translated, your single logic breakpoint requires two low-level breakpoints, and the path in the second case hits both of them.

Comment: jmcilhinney, Craig. Thanks for the replies and confiirmation. The bug I mentioned was as I suspected my fault and nothing to do with the End If breakpoint behaviour but these little oddities are certainly interesting.

Comment: It is a code generation bug, the vb.net compiler removes the If-statement (since the expression is always true) and replaces it with nops.  That confuzzles the debugger, it actually sets two breakpoints.   Another way to see that is by using Debug > Windows > Disassembly after the breakpoint hits, note how it thinks there are two methods.  Nothing we can do about it, use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to make them aware of it.

Comment: Thanks Hans. As always, logical and understandable but this odd breakpoint behaviour is not only for If statements that are always true. If I set a variable, as suggested by VBShaper, then the EndIf breakpoint will behave in this same odd way depending on the value of the variable. The compiler has no idea whether the If statement will be true or not but the End If breakpoint will still behave as I have described.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a variable a = 1. If that does not work. You may try copying the code to a new project and try your code there.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be responsive to the question.  If it is, it needs more detail.  Why should the questioner do this?  How does it solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks VBShaper but it was not so much the code itself that was giving me concern. My example "If" statement of If "1=1" is clearly ridiculous and I used it only as an example. If I take your suggestion of using a variable "If a=1" then if a=0 (False) the End If statement will need only one continue from a breakpoint. If I set a=1 (True)  the breakpoint will need 2 continues. It is just this odd breakpoint "one or two continues" behaviour that I was questioning, not the code itself. And FYI, copying code to a new project is a solution I have often used when the going gets tough. Thanks.